# How to manage state for a 2D-grid UI in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, animation, android-jetpack-compose

I have created 2 **animated** grid apps using **LazyVerticalGrid** ([Snake Game App](https://github.com/crjacinro/compose-snake-desktop) and [Path Finding Visualizer](https://github.com/crjacinro/compose-path-finding)).

The program works as expected but for the Path Finding app, there is a much complex animation and calculation going on (compared to the Snake app) and I notice a slight lag or slowness on the animation and I was thinking that it's probably on how compose manage state in a 2d grid.

As of the current version (1.0.0-rc01), we can compose a 2d-grid UI with this code:

```
@Composable
fun GridUI(gridData: List<GridData>) {
    LazyVerticalGrid(cells = GridCells.Fixed(40)) {
        items(gridData) {
            Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
                // Cell Ui here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the composable accepts 2d list of grid data, transformed into a linear list (in this case 40 rows). For my path finding app, the 2d-grid is around 20 x 40 which will produce about 800 cells or 800 linear grid size.

For every frame in the animation (20 ms delay per frame) this entire grid state is updated and according to the idea of state management of Compose, it calculates the diff between the previous state and the current state of data.

So the question; Is Compose smart enough to calculate a the diff between 2d grid (around 800 cells in this example) and recompose every 20 ms or is there any other way to improve the state management approach for grids with this use case?

For instance in the snake app, in every frame, the snake just moves to a direction and the rest of the UI stays the same so the change in the grid state is just very minimal. Is there a way in Compose to take advantage of this case to improve recomposition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your a relative expert in Compose, so I'm going to give the everyone-else answer first, and then loop back to your question.

In general, you should not be trying to reason about what the Compose Compiler will or will not do, as these optimizations are implementation details and subject to change at any time and without notice.  In particular, questions where a user is trying to avoid having a particular widget get recomposed are an indication that the user is thinking about the problem wrong.  Correctness dictates that you neither know nor care when or how often your composable recomposes, and Compose should be free to re-run your composable on every frame if it so desires.  Correctness aside, the second most common reason users ask is that they are doing premature performance optimization; only optimize after you've measured a problem.

Now for your specific use case: You have clearly done the measurement, and are looking to optimize...

(1) My first question is, is your `GridData` class annotated as `androidx/compose/runtime/Immutable`?  If not, that's the first thing I'd do.  Annotating the class as immutable will cause Compose to use a `.equals` call to determine if the value has changed, and will thus potentially perform much better.

(2) Try defining your own Composable called `GridCell` which takes in only a single `GridData`, and renders the cell.  Even if this `GridCell` invokes a Column, it won't be inline unless explicitly marked as such.  Don't mark it as inline.  I don't know for sure if this is related, but it might be that because Column is an inline function, the parent scope is being completely recomposed every time any child changes, and that could be expensive.  Using a non-inline GridCell composable should help eliminate this possibility.

(3) Instead of passing in a new List every time, create a single list of mutable GridData objects, where GridData is a class with one or more fields backed by mutableStateOf (`val cellColor by mutableStateOf(...)`) and instead of re-creating your list and GridData, just update an existing grid.  This is especially useful for cases where most of the grid is the same from frame-to-frame, but a few elements change.